Disk error by partioning dual boot and running fsck -b
so after I partitioned with mini partion tool the drive containing Linux and windows 11 broke the windows so I hoped on linux trying to fix it but the linux partition sustained some damage too it wouldn't mount so I ran fsck -b to try and fix it with the backs superblock data cause fsck would not run cause of superblock error after I ran fsck -b it removed all my files and created a folder lost+found completely empty how do I fix this I forgot the original superblock byte

Linux cannot fix Windows. General rule is Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Sounds like you destroyed system, easiest is to just totally reinstall both Windows & Linux & restore backups. Use Windows tools to see if you can fix Windows. Windows tools are often better working on NTFS partitions. In Linux testdisk may show partitions and photorec find files. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk. If deeper search shows files immediately back those up.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery Photorec requires separate backup drive & takes long time as it scans drive.

Well I reinstalled windows but the linux install is broken after I ran the fsck -b to try and fix the windows and Linux partition I managed to repair the windows volume with testdisk and backed up the data but the linux partition can't be fixed with testdisk

Testdisk/Photorec are for data recovery, not to fix anything.
